Error en OpenSIPS al modificar el encabezado Route y eliminar comas en el método BYE
Estoy trabajando con OpenSIPS 3.1 y estoy intentando modificar el encabezado Route en los mensajes SIP del método BYE. El objetivo es eliminar todas las comas presentes en el encabezado Route si el mensaje BYE proviene de una IP específica.
Contexto:
Quiero dar prioridad al manejo de mensajes INVITE.
Si el método es BYE y proviene de una IP específica, necesito modificar el encabezado Route eliminando las comas y luego reenviar el mensaje.
Estoy utilizando append_hf para agregar el encabezado modificado.
Código Actual:
route[sequential_request] {
    if (has_totag()) {
        if (loose_route()) {
            route(fix_to_header);
            if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                record_route();
                route(relay);
                exit;
            } else if (is_method("BYE") && $si == "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX") {
                xlog("Received BYE request from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\n");
                if (is_present_hf("Route")) {
                    xlog("Original Route header: $hdr(Route)\n");

                    # Modificar el encabezado Route eliminando todas las comas
                    append_hf("Route: $(hdr(Route){s/,//g})\r\n");

                    xlog("Modified Route header: $(hdr(Route){s/,//g})\n");
                }
                route(relay);
                exit;
            }
            route(relay);
        } else {
            if (is_method("ACK")) {
                if (t_check_trans()) {
                    route(relay);
                } else {
                    sl_send_reply(404, "Not Here");
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                sl_send_reply(404, "Not Here");
                exit;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (is_method("INVITE")) {
            trace("tid", "d", "sip|xlog");
        } else if (!is_method("CANCEL")) {
            trace("tid", "t", "sip|xlog");
        }
    }

}
Problema:
Al intentar ejecutar este código, obtengo el siguiente error:
less

Aug 19 06:01:44 sippy1 OpenSIPS_3.1[655]: Aug 19 06:01:44 [1]
ERROR:core:parse_transformation: invalid transformation: {s/,//g} ())!
Aug 19 06:01:44 sippy1 OpenSIPS_3.1[655]: Aug 19 06:01:44 [1]
ERROR:core:parse_transformation: error parsing [{s/,//}] Preguntas
Específicas:

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de modificar el encabezado Route eliminando las comas?
¿Hay alguna alternativa recomendada para manejar este tipo de modificación en OpenSIPS?
¿Cómo podría mejorar la lógica de mi script para asegurarme de que se procesa correctamente el encabezado Route?
Lo que ya he intentado:
He revisado la documentación del módulo sipmsgops, pero no encuentro una manera clara de manejar la eliminación de comas en el encabezado Route.
Intenté utilizar transformaciones y manipulación de cadenas directamente en el encabezado, pero sigo obteniendo errores de sintaxis.
Agradezco cualquier consejo o solución que puedan ofrecer para resolver este problema.
